# Error:Execution failed for task ':Application:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, exception, task

While running my android application in android studio, I got the following error:

> Error: Execution failed for task':App:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: 
>   duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/LayoutRes.class

Where does that error come from / how to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have added `com.android.support:support-annotations:` two times. Surely, not directly, but one of your dependencies depends on it. Run from console (inside project folder): `gradlew app:dependencies` and see what depends on support annotations library.

Then, [exclude dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies)

Comment: howto overcome this issue@R. Zago`rski

Comment: I have added a description. Read it carefully and follow.

Comment: Information:Modules "App-App", "google-play-services_lib", "ActionBarSherlock", "FacebookSDK", "library" and 2 others were fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes i got this one @ R. Zagórski